How to create liquidity lock on solana meme coin which is on raydium liquidity pool
I am new to solana development so need the help on locking the liquidity on solana meme coin project. We have created a solana meme coin and added the liquidity to it on raydium. Liquidity on this meme coin is currently unlocked and I need to lock it. Please suggest which CLI program  or some solana rpc call or custom contract, I can use to lock it.
